# I'm having a problem on Acumatica's Generic Inquriy with Entry Screen "This form cannot be automated"

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to make a Generic Inquiry list with Ability to add records in a form, likewise implementation of Expense Claim Screen. I'm having an error that says "This form cannot be automated", it works sometimes, but sometimes it does not. Is there something wrong on my configuration?

*edited
here is the screenshot
[image: Generic Inquiry Error]

Comment: It seems like there is some error with the page you are trying to use as the entry form. If you open the form you are trying to use as the entry form and go to Tools > Web Service in the upper right area of the page - you might see the error on the page. In older versions the web service entry might be under Help vs Tools menu

Comment: Thanks Brendan. Will try to look at it

Comment: Hi Brendan, still not working, the fields in navigation tab not auto populating, do I have to set something on the DAC?

Comment: Could be the fields are not marked as key and not the primary dac of the entry page. I think to get it to work you need to make sure you do not have the error on the page cannot be automated. Usually you can find the error on why its not automated via the Help/Tools menu of the page you are looking to navigate to